# Has anyone read a short story about a boy and a ship that end up connecting and training each other?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I think it was a prototype/ai type ship that learns from experience, but somehow its trained pilot was gone. An injured street kid gets on board, and because of his distrust, the ship has to trick him to eat/accept medical help etc. Eventually the kid learns about the ship, but the other prototype ships with actual pilots come looking for the missing one. The ship with the street kid outperforms the ones with trained pilots, because it learned deception from the street kid. Kid gets to stay with the ship.

Read probably sometime between 2000-2010

Comment: What kind of "ships" are we talking about? Ocean-going ships, or riverboats? Or space ships?

Comment: I'm thinking a land and/or airgoing vessel of some kind. Plane? Not watergoing, and I don't think they went into space. Good question.